# MultiResourceItemReader's parsing cached using spring-batch-admin

Tags: caching, spring-batch-admin

For each job launch, the content of file scanning is different, files being replaced by others.
But unless I stop and restart the web application (based on spring-batch-admin),
the step fails because the result of file scanning is cached somewhere.
So, the reader (MultiResourceItemReader) is unable to find files which are no more on the disk but were processed by the previous instance.
I would to know how to clear the cache without having to restart the web application.

Thanks.